# octane:reload on centos 8 doesn't reflect changes

Tags: laravel, centos, swoole

```
Octane Version: 1.0.8
Laravel Version: 8.49.2
PHP Version: 8.0.8
Server & Version: Swoole 4
Database Driver & Version: PostgreSQL 12
```

On local (Ubuntu 20.04) the reload works well, but on the server (Centos 8) the reload did not reflect the changes. After executing the octane:reload command, it shows `INFO Application change detected. Restarting workers ...` , but the changes were not affected. octane:start --watch with chokidar too did not help

Comment: Did you find any solution?